# Saving value in "jq" variable causes "Cannot iterate over null" problem

Tags: json, jq

Such command works successfully:

```
jq '.values[].data | .items[]' my.json
"url1"
"url2"
...
```

And simple attempt to save variable leads to fail:

```
jq '.values[].data as $p | .items[]' my.json
jq: error (at my.json:0): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

It looks like I follow the syntax. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
.values[].data as $p
```

you would have to write:

```
.values[].data | . as $p
```

### Semantics of `BAR as $BAR`

`as` behaves like a shunt; that is,

```
FOO | BAR as $BAR | ...
```

is the same as:

```
FOO | . as $FOO | (BAR as $BAR | $FOO | ...)
```

assuming that `...` does not reference a variable named `$FOO`.